# Remove element for certain screen sizes

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I am currently creating a responsive web design using media queries. For mobile devices I want to remove my JS slider and replace it with something else. I have looked at `.remove()` and a few other things from the JQuery library, however these have to be implemented into the HTML and I cannot think of a work around from the css angle.

Comment: You can hide an element and show another depending on screen size using media query from `css`.

Answer (score 36):

Do you need to remove them, or just hide them?  If just hiding is okay, then you can combine media queries with `display:none`:

```css
#mySlider{
   display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) 
{
   #mySlider
   {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: Depends on whether hiding it would still load the slider and images as one of the reasons of changing the slider other than due to the size of it is to create a lighter weight element for quicker mobile load times.

Comment: It will still load if you're hiding it.

Answer (score 9):

You can hide an element and show another depending on screen size using media query from `css` , this is from one of my  live projects (I use this to show/hide icon)

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px)
{
   .icon-12{ display:none; } // 12 px
   .icon-9{ display:inline-block; }  // 9px
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not a 100% sure what you mean. But I created a class "no-mobile" that I add to elements that should not be shown on mobile devices. In the media query I then set no-mobile to display: none;.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .nomobile {
      display:none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jquery function **addClass()** and **removeClass()** or `removeAttr()` to fulfill your purpose.

Example:

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
   if(window.innerWidth < 500) {
      $("#slider").removeAttr("style");
   }
});
```

Or you can also use media query as follow :

```css
#mySlider{
   display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
   #mySlider {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: I believe playing with display property is not ideal, it hides DOM element, but still keeps it on a page. Which makes DOM dirty, with hidden never-used elements. Is there decision to have different DOM structure for destops and mobile devices? Other words, can we differentiate device type not on css level, but on html-js level?