# How to make logo visible under 500px screen size and invisible over 501px?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Using Wordpress Theme Sela
i'm using background image and logo, i'm looking to make the logo show only in mobile screens.

the website is pontifexgrp.com

Comment: Use a media query, which there's loads of tutorials for. Give it a shot and come on back once you've actually tried something first. :)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove element for certain screen sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762354/remove-element-for-certain-screen-sizes)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're trying to take advantage of two features here, media queries and display settings. Media queries allow you to target devices based on screen settings. First, you'd need `@media screen` to make sure the user is viewing your site on an actual screen and not a screenreader or a printed sheet of paper.

Next, you'll want to specify the screen size. You can do this using either `max-width` to specify rules that only apply to screens *smaller* than your number, in your case for phones, or `min-width` to specify rules that only apply to screens *larger* than your number, in your case for all other devices. Considering the logo seems to work as is, no need to make it appear when its already there, better to make it disappear otherwise, so I'd go with a `min-width: 500px` rule that makes the logo disappear when the screen is larger than a phone screen.

Finally, there are a few different ways of making something disappear, chiefly `display: none` and `visibility: hidden`. The difference between these two is that `display: none` actually removes the item, so if it was being used by the theme to take up space, this will break the page. On the other hand, `visibility: hidden` just makes the item invisible, but any space it is being used to take up still gets taken up, so this is the safer bet.

I checked your site, and the logo has the class `site-logo`, so you can do what you're trying to accomplish as follows:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .site-logo {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

**I tried this on your site and here's what I got:**

[image: New Site]

Comment: Wow thank you very much, i've always had trouble with this sort of things! >.< i'm going to use this for future reference! thank you thank you! 

I get confused with @media since i'm pretty new at using them.. i'll keep on learning though, you've definitely giving me a great lesson.